# Remove a header from a file during parsing

Tags: bash, parsing, sed

My script gets every .csv file in a dir and writes them into a new file together. It also edits the files such that certain information is written into every row for a all of a file's entries. For instance this file called "trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160110.csv":

```
"",1/10/2016
"Timezone",-6

"Serial No.","7C000000395C1641"
"Location:","LS_trap_10c"
"High temperature limit (�C)",20.04
"Low temperature limit (�C)",-0.02
"Date - Time","Temperature (�C)"
"8/10/2015 16:00",30.0
"8/10/2015 18:00",26.0
"8/10/2015 20:00",24.5
"8/10/2015 22:00",24.0
```

Is converted into this format

```
LS_trap_10c,7C000000395C1641,trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160110.csv,Location:,LS_trap_10c
LS_trap_10c,7C000000395C1641,trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160110.csv,High,temperature,limit,(�C),20.04
LS_trap_10c,7C000000395C1641,trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160110.csv,Low,temperature,limit,(�C),-0.02
LS_trap_10c,7C000000395C1641,trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160110.csv,Date,-,Time,Temperature,(�C)
LS_trap_10c,7C000000395C1641,trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160110.csv,8/10/2015,16:00,30.0
LS_trap_10c,7C000000395C1641,trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160110.csv,8/10/2015,18:00,26.0
LS_trap_10c,7C000000395C1641,trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160110.csv,8/10/2015,20:00,24.5
LS_trap_10c,7C000000395C1641,trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160110.csv,8/10/2015,22:00,24.0
```

I use this script to do this:

```
dos2unix  *.csv
gawk '{print FILENAME, $0}' *.csv>>all_master.erin
sed -i 's/Serial No./SerialNo./g' all_master.erin 
sed -i 's/ /,/g' all_master.erin
gawk -F, '/"SerialNo."/ {sn = $3} 
         /"Location:"/  {loc = $3} 
         /"([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"/ {lin = $0}
                        {$0 =loc FS sn FS $0}1' all_master.erin > formatted_log.csv
sed -i 's/\"//g' formatted_log.csv
sed -i '/^,/ d' formatted_log.csv
rm all_master.erin
printf "\nDone\n"
```

I want to remove the messy header from the formatted_log.csv file. I've tried and failed to use a sed, as it seems to remove things that I don't want to remove. Is sed the best way to approach this problem? The current sed fixes some problems with the header, but I want the header gone entirely. Any lines that say "serial no." and "location" are important and require information. The other lines can be removed entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you edited your script before posting; as it stands, it will not produce the posted output (`all_master.erin` should be `$(<all_master.erin)` except in the first occurrence).

You don’t specify many vital details of the format of your input files, so we must guess them. Here are my guesses:

- You ignore the first two lines and the subsequent empty third line.
- The 4th and 5th lines are useful, since they provide the serial number and location you want to use in all lines of that file
- The 6th, 7th and 8th lines are useless.
- For each file, you want to discard the first four lines of the posted output.

With these assumptions, this is how I would modify your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dos2unix  *.csv
awk -vFS=, -vOFS=, \
   '{gsub("\"","")}
    FNR==4{s=$2}
    FNR==5{l=$2}
    FNR>8{gsub(" ",OFS);print l,s,FILENAME,$0}' \
   *.csv > formatted_log.CSV
printf "\nDone\n"
```

**Explanation of the `awk` script:**

First we delete all double quotes with `gsub("\"","")`. Then, if the line number is 4, we set the variable `s` to the second field, which is the serial number. If the line number is 5, we set the variable `l` to the second field, which is the location. If the line number is greater than 8, we do two things. First, we execute `gsub(" ",OFS)` to replace all spaces with the value of the output field separator: this is needed because the intended output makes two separate fields of date and time, which were only one field in the input. Second, we print the line preceded by the values of `l`, `s` and `FILENAME` as requested.

Note that I’m using the (questionable) Unix trick of naming the output file with an all-caps extension `.CSV` to avoid it being wrongly matched by a subsequent `*.csv`. A better solution would be to put it in another directory, but I don’t know anything about your directory tree so I suggest you modify the output file name yourself.

Comment: can you explain what     FNR>8{gsub(" ",OFS);print l,s,FILENAME,$0}' \
does?

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk to remove anything
with less than 3 columns in your final file:

`awk 'NF>=3' file`

Comment: This is a good idea, but it doesn't seem to do anything to my file.